# Scala + Play Framework: Basic Form

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to create a basic form with username/password and save the results in a database, just to get familiar with it.

Step one and I'm a little stuck: I can't get the app to render the form in my browser. Once I can do that, I figure I'll move on to getting my database set up. But every time I try to run my app, I get this error:

> Cannot write an instance of play.api.Form[models.User] to http response. Try to define a Writable[play.api.Form[models.User]]

I spent my entire day searching for the solution to this problem. Here are my files:

`Application.scala` (controller class):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import models._


class Application extends Controller {

  val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "username" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(userForm)
  }
}
```

`users.scala.html` (view):

```
@(user: Form[models.User])(implicit message: Messages)

@import helper._

@main(Messages("Feedback")) {
    <h2>@Messages("Leave Feedback")</h2>
    <form>
        @inputText("username")
        @inputText("password")
        <input type="submit" value="@Messages("send")">
    </form>
}
```

Routes file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot write an instance of play.api.Form[models.User] to http response. Try to define a Writable[play.api.Form[models.User]]

The complied error has given the hint that the data sent should be a Form which is just the userForm as for your question, and the Form should be filled with models.User

As for your question, you just need to do the following things

Firstly, define a form Models.User data you want to send in your controller.

```
val userData = Models.User("name", "password")//Models.User is a case class
```

if you want to send a form data to the views, you must define a variable data with the type of ***Models.User*** firstly. In your code, you have created a form data **userForm** mapping to the **models.user**. The next thing you should do is to create a value **userData** with type of **models.user**, which can be filled  into the **userForm** using ***userForm.fill(userData)***. Then the userForm filled full of **Models.User** data can be sent to the views.

Then, send it to the views using the following way

```
Ok(views.html.users(userForm.fill(userData)))
```

So, all the answer to your question will like this

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import models._


class Application extends Controller {

val userForm = Form(
 mapping(
   "username" -> nonEmptyText,
   "password" -> nonEmptyText
 )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)

def index = Action {
    val userData = Models.User("yourName", "yourPassword")// the Models.User value is a case class
    Ok(views.html.users(userForm.fill(userData)))
 }
}
```

Have a good luck